# PHP Arrays: Pop an array of single-element arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays

Using a proprietary framework, I am frequently finding myself in the situation where I get a resultset from the database in the following format:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => array(1) {
    ["id"] => int(241)
  }
  [1] => array(1) {
    ["id"] => int(2)
  }
  [2] => array(1) {
    ["id"] => int(81)
  }
  [3] => array(1) {
    ["id"] => int(560)
  }
  [4] => array(1) {
    ["id"] => int(10)
  }
}
```

I'd much rather have a single array of ids, such as:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => int(241)
  [1] => int(2)
  [2] => int(81)
  [3] => int(560)
  [4] => int(10)
}
```

To get there, I frequently find myself writing:

```
$justIds = array();
foreach( $allIds as $id ) {
  $justIds[] = $id["id"];
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you using the good method? In most frameworks, there are methods like fetchCol() to handle the 1-dimensonal special cases...

Comment: It is the case that a fetchCol() style method is available, but in many cases I don't control what is actually fetching the information from the database (API calls etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$out = array_map('array_shift', $in);
```

e.g.

```
$in = array(
  array("id" => 241),
  array ("id" => 2),
  array ("id" => 81),
  array ("id" => 560),
  array ("id" => 10)
);
$out = array_map('array_shift', $in);
var_dump($out);
```

prints

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(241)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(81)
  [3]=>
  int(560)
  [4]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to use `reset` instead because `array_shift` changes the passed array. EDIT: just tested, using 'reset' gives a 6% improvement with your example on my windows debug build.

Comment: What would a solution using reset look like?

Comment: Just replace `array_shift` by `reset`.

Answer (score 6):

With PHP 5.3 you can do

```
$justIds = array_map(
    function($cur) {
        return $cur['id'];
    },
    $allIds
);
```

With PHP < 5.3 you'd have define a regular function and then pass the name as string to array_map().

Comment: Actually VolkerK's version with array_shift might be nicer than my custom callback

Comment: On the other hand this version works even if the input array contains arrays with more than one element regardless of the order. +1

Comment: I marked VolkerK's as best answer because it addresses the specific example but there are enough times where I will need to handle multi-element sub-arrays that I will be able to add both techniques to my arsenal. Thanks to you both!